# Nginx refuses to read custom nginx.config when dockerized

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have created a custom nginx.conf file with simple proxy and I have put it in the root of my project.

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    #include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

      server { # simple reverse-proxy
      root /var/www/html;
    listen       80;

    # pass requests for dynamic content to rails/turbogears/zope, et al
    location /test1/ {
      proxy_pass      http://dumy/test1/;
    }

    location /test2/ {
      proxy_pass      http://dumy/test2/;
    }
  }
}

#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

When I run my nginx server locally (ubuntu) everything works perfect. The proxies work as they should.

When I try to run it through docker container, no matter what I do, the proxies do not work.

my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine AS builder
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run prod

FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx","-g", "daemon off;", "-c", "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"]
```

I have to use nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged because the app will eventually deployed in openshift.
The above docker file will create the docker image.

When I run:

```
 docker run -p 8080:8080 <image>
```

The container will be created and start. But no matter what I do , it will start with the default configuration.

This is what I get if I run

```
nginx -T
```

inside the container :

```
# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

As you can see, my nginx.conf file is completely ignored.  It's like

```
 "-c", "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
```

from cmd inside the Dockerfile never runs.
I have tried to pass the command in docker run with no luck.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Is it possbile you've missed your build step? `docker build -t mynginx .` and then `docker run -P mynginx`

Comment: No,  I build the project. I did not write it  because nothing would work without "docker build . "

Comment: Which config file do you see when you run `docker run mynginx cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`?

Comment: The right one. My nginx.conf file is there.

Comment: remove the semicolon from `"daemon off;"` in the last lne of your Dockerfile, or re-order so it's the last argument in the list

Comment: It gives me an error if I do. It is mandatory..
The error is :"unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line"

Comment: try this: `CMD ["nginx", "-c", "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf", "-g", "daemon off;"]`

Comment: Tried it , it gives me this error and the pod does not start.
The error: "nginx: invalid option: "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After A LOT of trial and error I have finally managed to make this work. First of all change image inside Dockerfile from: nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged to nginx:alpine

Second, give the right privileges to the user inside the openshift. Run :

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid system:serviceaccount:<<NAMESPACE>>:default
```

Next a default.conf file should be created inside the root of the project and have the same contents inside the server {} object as the custom nginx.conf file. Finally the correct configuration on all files should be made.

default.conf:

```
    server { # simple reverse-proxy
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    listen       80;

    # pass requests for dynamic content to rails/turbogears/zope, et al
    location /test1/ {
      proxy_pass      http://dumy/test1/;
    }

    location /test2/ {
      proxy_pass      http://dumy/test2/;
    }
  }
```

nginx.conf:

```
events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    #include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

      server { # simple reverse-proxy
      root /var/www/html;
    listen       80;

    # pass requests for dynamic content to rails/turbogears/zope, et al
    location /test1/ {
      proxy_pass      http://dumy/test1/;
    }

    location /test2/ {
      proxy_pass      http://dumy/test2/;
    }
  }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine AS builder
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run prod

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

RUN chgrp -R root /var/cache/nginx /var/run /var/log/nginx && \
    chmod -R 770 /var/cache/nginx /var/run /var/log/nginx
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx","-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Please keep in mind that in both default.conf and nginx.conf files the root inside the server object should be changed to match the path of your static files html files. in my case the path inside the docker was :  /usr/share/nginx/html so the entire root variable should be :

```
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
```

Comment: thank you for ending with my misery. I've spent hours on this.